# Express a given sinus as a set of base vectors and vice-versa

Tags: python, fft, trigonometry

Say, I have a given sinus:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as py

x = np.arange(0, 1000, 1)
y = np.sin(x/40)
py.plot(x, y, color='red')
```

[image]

...now I want to adjust to it a proper set of vectors, so I would get something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve something similar to this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You have to first sample your signal :
Y(k) = y(k*T) where 1/T is your sample rate frequency.

Then just plot line between each Y(k) and Y(k+1).

Be careful when choosing your frequency (see more Nyquist theorem).